# setfacl: Are these two commands the same?

Tags: permissions, acl

I have a deployment script (based on capifony) that sets te permissions on specific servers for a Symfony2 installation. It contains the following two commands to do this for several directories:

```
setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache
setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache
```

These two commands are on the Symfony2 site as a way to fix the permissions, however, these looked strikingly similar to me. So I had a look at the manpages for `setfacl`, and from what I could understand, the second command does exactly what the first one does with an additional option (which I don't quite understand). My question is, is my assumption correct? If so, would it have the same effect if I removed the first command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first command will change the permissions of any pre-existing files/directories. The `-d` in the second command is critical to setting the default permissions going forward for any directories, which in turn will provide a default set of ACLs for any files within these directories.

**NOTE:** That in both instances the commands will run recursively via the `-R` switch.

Regarding the `-d` switch, from the `setfacl` man page:

```
   -d, --default
       All operations apply to the Default ACL. Regular ACL entries in the 
       input set are promoted to Default ACL entries. Default ACL  entries
       in the input set are discarded. (A warning is issued if that happens).
```

This excerpt also explains it fairly well:

> There are two types of ACLs: access ACLs and default ACLs. An access ACL is the access control list for a specific file or directory. A default ACL can only be associated with a directory; if a file within the directory does not have an access ACL, it uses the rules of the default ACL for the directory. Default ACLs are optional.

*Source: [8.2. Setting Access ACLs](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-acls-setting.html).*

#### Example

Say I have this directory structure.

```
$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- dirA
|   |   `-- file1
|   `-- fileA
`-- file1

2 directories, 3 files
```

Now let's set the permissions using the first `setfacl` command in your question:

```
$ setfacl -R -m u:saml:rwx -m u:samtest:rwX .
```

Which results in the following:

```
$ getfacl dir1/ file1
# file: dir1
# owner: saml
# group: saml
user::rwx
user:saml:rwx
user:samtest:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x

# file: file1
# owner: saml
# group: saml
user::rw-
user:saml:rwx
user:samtest:rwx
group::rw-
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

Without the `-dR` command run here, new directories would not be covered by your ACLs:

```
$ mkdir dir2

$ getfacl dir2
# file: dir2
# owner: saml
# group: saml
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

But if we remove this directory and run the `setfacl -dR ...` command and repeat this operation above:

```
$ rmdir dir2
$ setfacl -dR -m u:saml:rwx -m u:samtest:rwX .
```

Now the permissions look quite different:

```
$ getfacl dir1/ file1 
# file: dir1/
# owner: saml
# group: saml
user::rwx
user:saml:rwx
user:samtest:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:saml:rwx
default:user:samtest:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: file1
# owner: saml
# group: saml
user::rw-
user:saml:rwx
user:samtest:rwx
group::rw-
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

And now our newly created directory will pick up these "default" permissions:

```
$ mkdir dir2

$ getfacl dir2
# file: dir2
# owner: saml
# group: saml
user::rwx
user:saml:rwx
user:samtest:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:saml:rwx
default:user:samtest:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Having these permissions in place on `dir2` will now enforce these permissions on files within `dir2` as well:

```
$ touch dir2/fileA
$ getfacl dir2/fileA 
# file: dir2/fileA
# owner: saml
# group: saml
user::rw-
user:saml:rwx           #effective:rw-
user:samtest:rwx        #effective:rw-
group::rwx          #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Comment: Ah, so just to confirm, you mean if we have the directory `app/cache` which contains a directory called `dev`, the first command will be applied to that, but not the second? And if later another directory is added (e.g. `prod`), the second command will set the permissions? If this is the not case, I should be able to skip the second command?

Comment: @HoshSadiq - no the `-R` is a recursive command, so the permissions apply. The `-d` guards if someone were to create a directory or move some directory into the tree later on so that it too would have this ACL applied.

Comment: That's great! Makes things a lot clearer :) Thanks!